# Struggling with setting up a Javascript class and dynamically setting an onclick event inside class

Tags: javascript, class, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with this assignment. I got the functionality to work where all the buttons will change styles to match the one that was clicked. But the problem is that the way the code needs to be written is wrong. I have it working by using a switch statement that checks the button that was clicked and then run another function that uses the value from the switch statement to update all of the buttons. These were the instructions I was given for the assignment:

I attempted to make a button class that stores the css class for the button. But I'm not sure what else to store in that class and I have been struggling to add an onclick event inside the class.

Here are the bootstrap buttons I'm working with:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-success">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-warning">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-info">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-light">Light</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-dark">Dark</button>
```

Here is what I have in my Javascript code

```
    // Update this code such that when the user clicks on a button, it will dynamically apply the css class of that button to all buttons. 
    // Make sure to encapsulate your code in a javascript class which collects and parses each button element.
    // Dynamically set the onclick event inside the class.

    
    class Button {
      constructor(coloring){
        this.coloring = coloring;
      }
      //Not sure how to add onclick event inside the class...
        
      //this.addEventListener("click", event => {
      //  updateButtons(this.coloring);
      //});
    }
    
    //Applies the css class of the button that was clicked to all buttons 
    function updateButtons(coloring) {
      var x = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.buttonGap');
      x.forEach( button => 
        button.classList.remove(button.classList[2])
      );
      x.forEach( button => 
        button.classList.add(coloring) 
      );
    }
    
    function getColor(buttonText) {
      switch(buttonText){
            case "Primary":
                return "btn-primary";
                break;
            case "Secondary":
                return "btn-secondary";
                break;
            case "Success":
                return "btn-success";
                break;
            case "Danger":
                return "btn-danger";
                break;
            case "Warning":
                return "btn-warning";
                break;
            case "Info":
                return "btn-info";
                break;
            case "Light":
                return "btn-light";
                break;
            case "Dark":
                return "btn-dark";
                break;
            }
    }
    
    window.onload = function(){
      //Selects all the buttons by including all shared classes
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.buttonGap');
        
        //Array to hold button objects
      var arr = [];
        
        //A dummy variable used to initialize object
      var x = "";
      
        //Goes through each button and initialize a new Button object that's added to an array
        //Currently not using the created objects...
        buttons.forEach( button => 
          arr.push(x = new Button(button.classList[2]))
        );
        
      buttons.forEach( button => 
        //arr.push(x = new Button(button.classList[2]))
          button.onclick = function() {
              console.log(getColor(button.innerHTML));
                var color = getColor(button.innerHTML);
                updateButtons(color);
            }
      );
      
    }
```

Comment: Your entire 26-line `switch` statement could be replaced by just `return "btn-" + buttonText.toLowerCase();`

Comment: @Marc Thanks, I can't believe overlooked doing that. But it's still the wrong way to do this assignment, I need to parse each button element in class and add an onclick event from within that class.

Comment: I have the web app running on my codepen if you want to see it running: [link](https://codepen.io/ebeyerle/pen/bGePQeo)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right path. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp: `onclick` is a property of the HTML button, so I would expect you to have something like

```
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-primary" onclick="onButtonClick(0)">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-secondary" onclick="onButtonClick(1)">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-success" onclick="onButtonClick(2)">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-danger" onclick="onButtonClick(3)">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-warning" onclick="onButtonClick(4)">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-info" onclick="onButtonClick(5)">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-light" onclick="onButtonClick(6)">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn buttonGap btn-dark" onclick="onButtonClick(7)">Dark</button>
```

and then

```
class Button {
  constructor(coloring){
    this.coloring = coloring;
  }

  applyNewStyle(coloring) {
    var color = "btn-" + coloring.toLowerCase()
    button.classList.remove(button.classList[2])
    button.classList.add(color) 
  );        
}

var buttons = []

function onButtonClick(buttonIndex) {
  buttons.forEach(button => 
    button.applyNewStyle(buttons[buttonIndex].classList[2]);
  );
}

window.onload = function() {
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.buttonGap')
    .map(button => new Button(button.classList[2]));
}
```

Some explanation. Let's start with `onload`, where you map each `button` element in the HTML to a `Button` object and store the latter in a global `buttons` variable. Then when users click on a button, you invoke a global function - this should not be inside the `Button` class because it needs to act on all buttons, so if you had this inside `Button` you would break the concept of encapsulation and modularity of Object Oriented Programming - and this global function invokes `applyNewStyle` on each `Button` object.

Does it solve your issue? Please consider flagging this answer as your valid answer.

Comment: I was instructed to have the onclick event be inside the class. I think I got it to work now, I got the onclick event inside the class. Now I just need to review my code and see if there is any way to improve it.

Comment: I believe the instruction you have received may mean that the onclick handler logic must be inside the class. If you have a Button class, and if you had there logic which changed other objects, that would break the single-responsibility principle of OOP. Each Button object should be in charge of itself only.